# Creating a map with custom class as key, from unordered map. However elements not useable due to const

Tags: c++, comparator, unordered-map

I'm trying to to map elements from my unordered map that contain  to a map that contain an Class T, int and sortBy being the compare class.

However I can't perform any functions on any elements in the map because they are all const. I have no idea how to make them not const, or why they were const in the first place.

```
unordered_map < int,LibrarySong> Library;
map < LibrarySong,int, LibrarySong:: sortbyPlay> sortedLibrary;

for(unordered_map<int,LibrarySong>:: iterator it = Library.begin(); it != Library.end(); ++it){
    sortedLibrary.insert(pair <LibrarySong,int> ( it->second, it->first));
}
for(map < LibrarySong,int>::iterator it=sortedLibrary.begin(); it != sortedLibrary.end(); ++it){
    cout << it->first.print() << endl; //Cant do anything because it is const
};
```

The LibrarySongs header has the struct

```
struct sortbyPlay {
    bool operator() (const LibrarySong &lhs ,const LibrarySong &rhs) const{
        return  lhs.numPlay < rhs.numPlay;
    }
};
```

I've tried removing the const in the function but that doesn't work either?

Maybe there is a better way to do this, I'm not sure. I was thinking of vectors and then using sort(), but I needed both values(probably could use a pair?) however I'm not sure if the const problem would still persist as well.

Comment: It looks to me, you're making things needlessly complicated.  Your unordered_map uses an int as the key and a Librarysong instance as the value.  Your map switches that around, then uses a special comparator.  Is numPlay the int? If so why not just leave it as the key and get the sorting you want and the LibrarySong isn't const any more.

Answer (score 0):

The `const`-ness of the map's comparator is completely irrelevant.

```
cout << it->first.print() << endl; //Cant do anything because it is const
```

The map's keys, the `first` values, are always `const`. As such, the `print()` method in the class must be a `const` method. Although your question completely fails to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's obvious that your `print()` method must be a `const` method, and it is not.

A class method, such as `print()`, does not need to modify its object. At least not in a sane class design. Therefore, you should not have any issues declaring your `print()` method as a `const` class method.